# nginx: Как перенаправить все url, в том числе .php на один файл index.php?

Tags: php, nginx, маршрутизация, редирект, роутер

прописал в конфиге локального домена то, что советуют все: "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;"

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name auth.local;

    root /var/www/auth;
    index index.php index.html;

    #location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #}
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Если набирать в адресной строке браузера {имя_домена}/sdcsdcsdcs/ или что-то подобное, то на index.php перекидывает, но если набирать {имя_домена}/DB.php пишет 404 Not Found, касается это и существующих и не существующих php url. Nginx перезапускал, fpm таже. Помогите, пожалуйста, не получается единую точку входа создать, чтобы потом маршрутизацию настроить! (

Comment: Дело в том, что при запросе /DB.php будет отрабатывать Location ~ \.php$ а не location /. Что у вас в snippets/fastcgi-php.conf ?

Comment: Алексей, спасибо, что уделили время! Вопрос решился путем того, что убрали  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; "uri" из этой строчки и занесли ее внутрь Location ~ \.php$